# Sublingual Spray Protocol

Tags: medications, procedure-purposes, drug-administration

I want to start learning about sublingual spray mechanisms.
Where can I start  with?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). This is an interesting question, but a rather broad one. It would be easier to answer if you shared some of your own research with us. For information on how the site works please take our [tour] or visit the [help] and [meta]. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. There are a number of different drugs that can be  delivered sublingually and they're not all used the same way so there is no single protocol. Or are you asking about the mechanism of action? Or how they're absorbed? Or even how the spray mechanism works? I really have no idea what you're asking. You'll have to be more specific.